# Find Checkbox from TD of row table with angularJS (IE vs Chrome)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox, html-table

I am struggling below scenario Table->row->td--> Checkbox with ng-model works fine in Chrome but it does not work in IE.

If I remove ng-model from Checkbox then it works in IE too but I do need ng-model

I do have 
Chrome version : 49.0.2623.87 
IE  version : 11.0.20 (KB3058515)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.objList = [{
      description: 'a'
    }, {
      description: 'b'
    }, {
      description: 'c'
    }, {
      description: 'd'
    }];

    $scope.toggleObjSelection = function($event, description) {
      // $event.stopPropagation();
      alert('checkbox clicked');

    }

    $scope.rowClicked = function(obj) {
      alert('row clicked');

      $("table tr").each(function() {

        $(this).find("td:first input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);

      });

    };
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <table ng-controller="ctrl">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-click="rowClicked(obj)" ng-repeat="obj in objList">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedObjs" />

          </td>
          <td>
            {{obj.description}}
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Click on any letter and all checkbox should be checked. (Chrome fine but IE does not work)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ng-model attribute on the checkox to be obj.selected and then set that attribute to true when the row is clicked.  Get rid of the jQuery and just use Angular.

You want each individual `obj` to have an attribute of selected and not just one attribute on $scope.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.objList = [{
      description: 'a'
    }, {
      description: 'b'
    }, {
      description: 'c'
    }, {
      description: 'd'
    }];

    $scope.toggleObjSelection = function($event, description) {
      // $event.stopPropagation();
      alert('checkbox clicked');

    }

    $scope.rowClicked = function(obj) {
        alert('row clicked');
        obj.selected = true;
      });

    };
  });
```

And then the updated html

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <table ng-controller="ctrl">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-click="rowClicked(obj)" ng-repeat="obj in objList">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.selected" />

          </td>
          <td>
            {{obj.description}}
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Jfraft, Thanks for your response but I need to know how to find td with checkbox in this case, I had just created prototype here                                    So I can not change that requirement to find checkbox under td of tr with ng-model and ng-change

Comment: What are you going to do with it when you find it?  Ultimately you should try to use Angular first and then jQuery.  If you really want, you access the $event object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick